# Plugin jquery doesn't launch

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, widget

I have a problem with a jquery plugin.

I just add a plugin like this :

```
$.ui.plugin.add("draggable", "smartguides", {
      //

     start: function(event, ui) {
          console.log('TOTO');
         }

      //
}
```

I set my options there :

```
    function draggableElementParameters(hash_id, is_smartguides)
{
    var datas = {
        containment:"#container_page",
        scroll: false,
        cursor:"pointer",
        opacity: 0.35,
        tolerance: 5,
        cancel: "#cr-stage",
        smartguides: '.element-container',
        stop: function (event, ui) {

            //

            });

        }, drag: function (event, ui) {

            //

        }
    };

    return datas;

}
```

Then I call it like this :

```
$("#element-edit").draggable(window.parent.draggableElementParameters({{ json_encode($element->hash_id) }}, Helpers.Utils.Cookie.isTrue('backend-contest-editor-is-draggable-help')));
```

And to finish, element-container is ok in my view.

The fact is the plugin is never triggered, the console.log never appear.

Any ideas about this bug ?

thank you !

Comment: Clément Probola : Did you add the reference to the plugin in your HTML?

Comment: Sumodh Nair : yup, I did !